# JBoss Richfaces: How to provide a different validation message to rich:calendar from within the xhtml implementation?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

The default implementation of rich:calendar renders the message **"Value must be a date"** when used like this and the user enters an invalid date, e.g. "13/13/2011".

```
<h:column>  
  <f:facet name="header">Opt-out Date</f:facet>
  <rich:calendar datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" enableManualInput="true" value="#{dtl.withdDt}"  />
</h:column>
```

The tag is pulling this key from messages_en.properties by default javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE=Value must be a date

I want the message to be **'Opt-out Date must be a date.'**

**Failed Attempt #1:**

```
   <h:column>   
      <f:facet name="header">Opt-out Date</f:facet>
      <rich:calendar validatorMessage="Opt-out Date must be a date." datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" enableManualInput="true" value="#{dtl.withdDt}"  />
    </h:column>
```

**Failed Attempt #2**
Create properties file entry:

```
validate.dateEntry={0} must be a date.
```

Then reference it:

```
<rich:calendar validatorMessage="validate.dateEntry" label="Opt-Out Date" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" enableManualInput="true" value="#{dtl.withdDt}" />
```

**Failed Attempt #3**

```
<rich:calendar validatorMessage="#{statusMessages.addToControlFromResourceBundle('Opt in Date',validate.dateEntry)}" label="Opt Out Date" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" enableManualInput="true" value="#{dtl.withdDt}" />
```

There is a wrong assumption that I'm making or concept that I'm not grasping.  Guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a conversion error, not a validation error. Use `converterMessage`, not `validatorMessage`.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a trick to passing in parameters?  Something like:  converterMessage="#{messages['validate.dateEntry'], 'Opt-in Date'}"